# Неработает курсор в PL/SQL, oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Уважаемые коллеги, прошу подсказать примером, или кинуть ссылкой годный мануал.

Пытаюсь проапдейтить n значений в 2х таблицах. При вызове процедуры ловлю исключение:

```
ORA-01422: Точная выборка возвращает количество строк больше запрошенного
```

Я так понимаю что данное исключение срабатывает в случае если **quittance_guid > 1**, мне и нужно отработать больше одного значения, как реализовать подобное в курсоре? Спасибо!

Код процедуры:

```
create or replace procedure itk_reconciliation_aborter(ptc_balance number)
is
--error_code number; 
error_message varchar2 (255);
quittance_guid varchar2 (36);

cursor reconciliation_aborter (ptc_data varchar2) is
 select 
  ptc.guid as ptc_guid
  ptc.chg_guid as chr_guid
from 
  payments_to_charge ptc   
where 
  ptc.guid = ptc_data;

begin

  if (ptc_balance is null or itk_is_number(ptc_balance) != 1)
    then raise_application_error(-21001, 'ITK - balance value is incorrect');
  end if;

  select ptc.guid into quittance_guid
  from 
   payments_to_charge ptc
  where 
   ptc.balance = ptc_balance;

if (quittance_guid is null or quittance_guid <= 0)
  then raise_application_error(-21001, 'ITK - Something wrong. Quittances not fount possibly.');
end if;

for updater in reconciliation_aborter(quittance_guid)
  loop
    update payments_to_charge ptc set ptc.is_active = 0 where ptc.guid = updater.ptc_guid;
    update charges chr set chr.reconcile_payments_status = 3 where chr.guid = updater.chr_guid;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line('Success!');

  exception
    when others then
      rollback;
      --error_code := SQLCODE;
      error_message := SQLERRM; 
   dbms_output.put_line(error_message);

 commit;
end itk_reconciliation_aborter;
```

Comment: Ошибку вызывает `select ptc.guid into quittance_guid`. Надо реализовать этот запрос через курсор? Курсоры делать Вы уже умеете. Останется сделать еще 1 цикл, в котором в курсор будут подставляться новые значения. Понятен ход моей мысли ?)

Comment: Если честно не совсем) еще один цикл в **updater**? Какие значения тогда перебирать в новом цикле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подумать в таком направлении:

```
create or replace procedure

...
cursor quittance_guid_cursor (p_ptc_balance varchar2) is
  select ptc.guid 
    from payments_to_charge ptc
  where 
   ptc.balance = p_ptc_balance;
...
begin
...

for qg in quittance_guid_cursor(ptc_balance)
loop
   for updater in reconciliation_aborter(qg.guid)
   loop
      update payments_to_charge ptc set ptc.is_active = 0 where ptc.guid = updater.ptc_guid;
      update charges chr set chr.reconcile_payments_status = 3 where chr.guid = updater.chr_guid;
   end loop;
end loop;
...
```

Идея в том, чтобы перебирать старое `quittance_guid` внутри цикла по курсору и подставлять из него значения в уже существующий цикл.

Comment: Ко сожалению, пока не догоняю, такой же результат, ведь в quittance_guid_cursor(ptc_balance) всеравно много данных засовывается( Добавил второй курсор, обернул первый цикл во новый...

Comment: Возможно я сам что-то путаю. Давно с этим не работал, но никто больше пока помогать нам не желает. По идее первый цикл будет построчно перебирать все строки, которые возвращает `quittance_guid_cursor` и для каждой строки будет вызывать вложенный цикл по второму курсору. В том и отличие курсора от `select .. into `, что в курсоре может лежать много строчек, а `select .. into` обязан вернуть одну строку. А в каком месте возникает ошибка? Вы попробовали так сделать?

Comment: Еще в голову мысль пришла. И в курсоре и в запросе вы обращаетесь к 1 и той же  табличке. Может их просто соединить в одном курсоре? простым join?

Comment: Задумался еще. А Вы убрали  `select ptc.guid into quittance_guid
  from 
   payments_to_charge ptc
  where 
   ptc.balance = ptc_balance;` ?